Ultimaker-Cura loaded and ran once but will not start
Please excuse what may be a simple question but I'm not a techi.
I'm running 22.04.4 LTS and have installed Ultimaker-Cura-5.7.2-linux-X64.Appimage. It started and worked fine the first time but since then it simply goes through the start-up process but fails to start with no error message.  When I look at the logs I get the following:

Can someone please enlighten me as to what I'm doing wrong?

I'd remove that and look up another source for Cura, that simply looks wicked.

Update:  I've tried to remove it by using sudo apt-get remove Ultimaker cura.  However all I get is:  Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package Ultimaker
So I can't run it and I can't remove it/

AppImage's are generally self-contained, so just delete the file and find something to replace it.

Sorry for what may be a silly question, but where should be files be located, I don't want to make things worse.

AppImages has no "official" place (as far as I know currently), for a single user machine I'd just keep them in a newly created AppImages/ folder in $HOME - but for multiple user access you probably need to create a group (for the users accessing them) and have the files in a generally accessible folder.

Well Hannu,  I've played around with it and I have no idea what I disturbed but it is now working.  Thanks for your assistance.
